# Does FASM uses Intel Syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I have tried compiling the following code in FASM:

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebp - 4], 1234567
```

It gave me an "Invalid Expression" error. However the following code worked:

```
mov DWORD [ebp - 4], 1234567
```

So does FASM uses Intel Syntax (I am assuming that the first line of code is compliant with Intel Syntax)?

Comment: There isn't a single intel syntax, unfortunately. It's mostly used as a term to differentiate from at&t, and has some general features such as dst, src operand order, but otherwise it has multiple flavors.  Consult the fasm manual to see what it accepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It gave me an "Invalid Expression" error.

Unlike MASM (and others), FASM doesn't need "ptr".

> So does FASM uses Intel Syntax?

Yes.

But there are some differences between different assemblers, for example:

Loading an address:

- MASM: `mov eax, offset memvar`
- FASM: `mov eax, memvar`

Loading a value:

- MASM: `mov eax, memvar`
- FASM: `mov eax, [memvar]`

I suggest you to read the [FASM Programmer's Manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual).